# Port forwarding from OpenVPN Client to Public Internet

Tags: routing, port-forwarding, iptables, openvpn

I need to forward port 44444 of my VPN client to the public internet with my public IP on port 44444, how i can do this?

The VPN Server is mine and I have root access.

Example how i can do this?
WANIP:44444-> 172.27.224.2:44444 (VPN LOCAL IP) ?

I'm trying with this but no success:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d WANIP -p tcp --dport 44444 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.224.2:44444
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 172.27.224.2 -p tcp --dport 44444 -j SNAT --to-source WANIP
```

Interface of WAN IP is eth0
Interface of VPN LOCAL IP is as0t0

Comment: Depending on where you buy your VPN service, most companies offer this as a payable extra.

Comment: I have root access @Cown

Answer (score 0):

> Example how i can do this? 213.205.12.32:8080 (WAN IP)-> 172.27.232.2:8080 (VPN LOCAL IP) ?

Assuming it's a linux server the actual NAT rule for the forwarding would be something along the lines of.

iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -d 213.205.12.32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.27.232.2:8080

Depending on the other details of your setup that you have not given this may be sufficient on it's own or further work may be needed. Other things you need to consider include.

1. If you have filtering rules in place those rules must let the traffic pass.
2. Replies to traffic that goes through a NAT must return through the same NAT.

Comment: I made changes to the question with more infos @plugwash, the server have clean Open VPN Access Server

Comment: Try using the sever's VPN IP rather than it's internet IP in the SNAT rule.